# Make multiple slideToggle´s with one script

Tags: jquery

I have multiple scripts looking like this:

```
$('#books').click(function(){
    $("#books_view").slideToggle("medium");
});

$('#newspapper').click(function(){
    $("#newspapper_view").slideToggle("medium");
});
```

The toggeling div always ending with "_view". I just wounder if its possible in this situation to write one script that works with all these toggle-divs instead of write one script to each toggle-div? Since all the toggeling divs end with exact same text this is maybe possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: means on click of book you want to toggle book as well as newspapper view ?

Comment: The functionality should still be exacly the same. Look at the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple selectors and then make use the clicked elements id to determine the id of the element to the toggled

```
$('#books, #newspapper').click(function(){
    $('#' + this.id + '_view').slideToggle("medium");
});
```

Comment: In this situation there is a need to add each ID in script, its ofcorse a solution with less code instead of all individual scripts. But issent there any way to to make the script automaticly "detect" if there is a belonging toggeling div if the name if its written in a exact way? So there is no need to add each ID in the script?

Comment: @Vode, you can add a class to all elements like `#books, #newspapper` like `toggler` then use it to register the handler like `$('.toggler').click(function(){
    $('#' + this.id + '_view').slideToggle("medium");
});`

Comment: Yes it was something like that script that was the idea but its not really working."<div id="books" class="toggler></div>" then "$('.toggler').click(function(){ $('#' + this.id + '_view').slideToggle("medium"); });", do you find any error in this code?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking like this ?

```
$('#books, #newspapper').click(function(){
    $('[id*=_view]').slideToggle("medium");
});
```

hope this help you.

Comment: Look at the answer "rid" wrote and the following comments, something like that script is the idea.